# Best Practice/Pattern for Transforming Java Objects

Tags: java

Let's say I have an application that is responsible for taking a vendor message and converting into a canonical message. For example:

```
public class MessageA extends VendorMessage { ... }
public class MessageB extends VendorMessage { ... }

public class MessageX extends CanonicalMessage { ... }
public class MessageY extends CanonicalMessage { ... }
```

Where MessageA maps to MessageX and MessageB maps to MessageY.

My approach is that I have one transformer class per message type to handle this conversion. In this example, I would have the following transformers:

```
public class MessageXTransfomer()
{
    public MessageX transform(MessageA message) {...}
}

public class MessageYTransfomer()
{
    public MessageY transform(MessageB message) {...}
}
```

My questions is really with the way I would ultimately invoke the transformers.

Since my process takes some VendorMessage as an input, I need to interrogate the type so I know which specific transformer to direct it to. For example, one approach might look like this:

```
public class TransfomerService
{
    MessageXTransformer messageXTransformer = new MessageXTransformer();
    MessageYTransformer messageYTransformer = new MessageYTransformer();

    public CanonicalMessage transform(VendorMessage message)
    {
        if (message instanceOf MessageA)
        {
            return messageXTransformer.transform((MessageA) message);
        }
        else if (message instanceOf MessageB)
        {
            return messageYTransformer.transform((MessageB) message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why, but I this approach just feels strange - as if I'm doing something wrong. Is there a best practice for this kind of problem that I should be using?

Note: I'm looking for the best approach without using any transformation frameworks, etc. Ideally, the pattern would be achievable using just basic Java.

Comment: The orthodox OO answer is to add a method to VendorMessage to transform it to a CanonicalMessage... i think the classic refactoring is something like 'convert conditional to polymorphism' or something like that.  But practical considerations may trump that.  Do the "simplest thing that could possibly work".  Don't overcomplicate things.  Focus on simplicity and readability.

Comment: @john_omalley disagree. As a short term solution having a method in a message itself works good, but in a long term 1) you are coupling vendor message domain with your canonical message domain 2) what if you can't modify vendor message at all and it is coming from a separate system? 3) when you start injecting things required for transformation your method immediately stops to work (you are not going to do injection into message, right?)

Comment: @john_omalley one more thing: it's breaking single responsibility principle :) The message should not be responsible for converting itself to something. It should be a responsibility of dedicated component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the answer of @javaguy however it is not complete. Of course it will be nice if you could use the specific transformer like in his later example, but if you can't you have to stick with TransformerFacade and kind of a StrategyPattern:

```
public class TransformerFacade {

    private Map<Class, VendorMessageToCanonicalMessageTransformer> transformers = new HashMap<>();
    { 
        // this is like strategies, the key may be class, class name, enum value, whatever
        transformers.put(MessageA.class, new MessageXTransformer());
        transformers.put(MessageB.class, new MessageYTransformer());
    }

    public CanonicalMessage transform(VendorMessage message) {
        return transformers.get(message.getClass()).transform(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispatch doesn't work in Java, since Java doesn't have multiple dispatch

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thanks, I thought it works, but just checked and you are right, removed that part from the answer!

Comment: I've upvoted your answer now :) PS If you want that kind of dispatch in Java, you have to simulate double dispatch with some visitor approach

Comment: Did the same ;) Yeah, I started to forget basics with all that enterprise stuff, visitor is nice but not for this kind of task.

Comment: I quite like this solution. I'd embroider it further with a couple of extra options: 1 maybe the transformer object can provide a "getMessageType" function so it can say which type it transforms - this means you only need the transformer objects to be able to correctly file them into a Map. 2. rather than use exact type, use a chain of responsibility pattern to ask each transformer "can you transform this message?" and use the function `isAssignableFrom` to determine if the types are compatible enough.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze 1 is ok, as for 2 I prefer avg O(1) in contrast to O(n), transformations are used very often in any app, so traversing everything each time may not be the best solution. But I agree the approach can be customized in any way which suits your needs.

Comment: Agreed. You could do both. Use chain to find nearest and cache in a map. Tends to O(1) pretty quickly. Depends on number of transformers too. O(1) and O(n) are nearly equivalent for n < 20. Especially since most CPU will be spent on transform not finding transformer.

Comment: I think this solution makes a lot of since and is probably what I'm looking for. My actual problem has a few more gotchas I will need to work around, but I think using this as a base will be a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply let every concrete `VendorMessage` return its corresponding `CanonicalMessage` by implementing an interface:

```
public interface Mapper<T> {

    T map();
}
```

Then, `MessageA` should implement this interface:

```
public MessageA implements Mapper<MessageX> {

    @Override
    public MessageX map() {
        MessageX message = ...;
        // fill message
        return message;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do the mapping in the `VendorMessage` class, then a strategy as suggested by Vadim Kirilchuk in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391377/1876620) would do the trick.